# Passing a struct of dynamic arrays by const reference

Tags: c++, struct, dynamic-arrays, pass-by-const-reference

If I have a struct in C++ containing dynamically allocated arrays, for example:

```
typedef struct foo {
  int* p;
} foo;

foo aFoo;
aFoo.p = new int[n];
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  aFoo.p[i] = 0;
```

How can I pass it by reference to a function so that the values stored in `aFoo.p[]` cannot be modified by the function?

If I declare `int func(foo const& aFoo) { ... }`, I get a compiler error if I try to modify the pointer `aFoo.p`, but not if I try to modify, for example, `aFoo.p[0]`. I'm also allowed to assign a new pointer `int* p2 = aFoo.p` and modify the values of `aFoo.p[]` through that.

If I were just passing the pointer, I believe this would be the difference between passing `int* const& p` and `const int* const& p`, but I'm not sure how to do it in this situation without declaring member `p` as a `const int*` in the struct definition (which would cause complications in other parts of the code).

Comment: you may do that if you change `int* p` to `std::vector<int> p;`

Comment: `typedef struct foo`  If you're using C++, this is not necessary.  All you need is `struct foo`.

Answer (score 1):

As you have noticed: the pointer cannot be modified, but the contents can.

If you want to keep pointers, I suggest getter/setter:

```
struct foo {
    void setP(int* p) { this->p = p; }
    int* getP() { return p; }
    const int* getP() const { return p; }
private:
    int* p;
};
```

Comment: correct answer to the question, but for pity's sake use a std::vector<int> in place of an int* ...

Answer (score 0):

You can forego the pointers and just use std::vector.  The following code shows this:

```
#include <vector>

struct foo {
  std::vector<int> p;
};

void someFunction(const foo& theFoo)
{
    theFoo.p[0] = 10;  // error.
}

int main()
{
   foo aFoo;
   aFoo.p.resize(1);
   someFunction(aFoo);
}
```

Live example (with compiler error): http://ideone.com/GuJn7d

Live example of pointer (showing no error): http://ideone.com/rVprYZ

Comment: Thank you. I cannot edit posts, but I don't think the code would work as written, since I do not have a constructor for the struct. I think I would need `foo aFoo;`, followed by `aFoo.p.resize(1);` or else use `push_back();` in `someFunction()`(aside from the stated compiler error)